# Choosing a BattleTag, how is it used?

Tags: diablo-iii, battle.net

To play Diablo 3, you have to choose a BattleTag. Blizzard says the name will represent me on battle.net. I already have an account name for Starcraft 2, and I'm wondering if I should use the same name for the BattleTag.

On the one hand, I'd would be nice to have the same name for all 'accounts', and also Blizzard might move to the BattleTag for Starcraft 2 one day. On the other hand, my Starcraft 2 name is rather sci-fi themed, and I think that would be weird / bad for the atmosphere in Diablo.

I'm wondering: How is the BattleTag is displayed in Diablo? Are there also character names, and what is more prominent?

<sup>*(And the following is a soft question and not really fitting for the site, but I'd still appreciate a comment, or an addition to your answer: What do the BattleTags tend to be like on average? I mean more thematic like, dunno, 'VigorTheConqueror' or 'DemonSlayer', or are there a lot of silly or off-topic names like 'Tassadar' or 'TupacLives'? ;-) I don't want to pick something that sticks out like a sore thumb. I'm probably overthinking this, but maybe someone could add their opinion.)*</sup>

Comment: Many Starcraft players do not want to be "found" thus they use something like |||||||||||||. There are a ton of similar accounts and many search engines, like sc2ranks.com do not allow special characters, thus it is not possible to query this name. The only possiblity to look at their accounts is to play against them. While this is not Diablo related the BattleTag system works the same.

Answer (score 2):

Your Battle Tag is the primary means of identifying yourself on Battle.net in Diablo III.  Most people I know use an existing online moniker for their Battle Tag.  Your Battle Tag is made unique by adding a hash mark and four digits to the end of your chosen name (i.e. #1234).  I don't usually go into the general chat channel, which is where you would see a lot of different names, but I'm sure there's a wide variety of Battle Tags from the extravagant to the mundane, and the silly to the serious.

While your Battle Tag identifies *you*, there are also character names that identify your characters.  For instance, in my friends list I might see MyFriend#1234 (the Battle Tag) was last seen online playing the Demon Hunter, Buffy (the character, and I really wish I had thought of that before) 5 hours ago.  That wording isn't exact, but you get the idea.  Character names are generally more thematic and extravagant because while visible, they're not used for identifying the player in any fashion.

In general, I usually ignore the character name of my friends as the class and level are better for identifying the character your friends are playing with.  For instance, I might tell my brothers I'm playing with my monk, which they know is a lower level character that I've been soloing with, so they know not to join my game.

One more important note: You can only change your Battle Tag once after it's been set.  You might also want to look at the [Naming Policy](http://us.battle.net/support/en/article/battletag-naming-policy).

Answer (score 1):

Your battletag is what most players will see from you.
The character name will only be displayed when someone access your profile.
You can even name all your characters the same, there's no "character name collision" concept on diablo 3.
So for example, if my battletag is 'stoldark', and my character name is 'JoeMonk' other players will see messages about me with my battle tag. For instance:
    "stoldark was slain"
    "stoldark found a new waypoint"
They will see I am playing with 'JoeMonk' if they see my profile.